# How to place Icon on top and bottom of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout, jpanel

I have a JPanel and after I click a button I want Icons to appear vertically one on top and after another click the second Icon on the bottom and so on.

So with every click the icon position alternates between top and bottom.

I tried many of the Layout managers but can't seem to get it to work as I want it to.

EDIT:
Example,

After the first click;

[image: After first click]

Second click,

[image: Second click]

Third click, another icon on top side, and so on.
The purpose of this is to be added to a chess game I am creating. So I want the dead pieces to appear on the appropriate player side (black or white). Black pieces go to the top and white pieces go on the bottom of the JPanel. hope this clears it up. thanks.

Comment: I'm having a tough time visualizing exactly what you're trying to do here. To swap icons, simply call `setIcon(...)` on a JLabel. To place JLabels on top and bottom use a BorderLayout, but again, I have no idea if this is what you're looking for. Please clarify your problem for us.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I added some images as example. The idea is after every button click an icon appears. the position of where the icon appears must alternate between the top of the JPanel and the bottom of the JPanel. The purpose of this is to be added to a chess game I am creating so I want the dead pieces to appear on the appropriate player side (black or white). Black pieces go to the top and white pieces go on the bottom of the JPanel. hope this clears it up. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Black pieces go to the top and white pieces go on the bottom of the JPanel.

I would suggest you want to nest panels instead of using a single panel. You could use a vertical BoxLayout for this:

```
Box deadWhitePieces = Box.createVerticalBox();
Box deadBloackPieces = Box.createVerticalBox();
Box deadPieces = Box.createVerticalBox();
deadPieces.add( deadBlackPieces );
deadPieces.add( Box.createVerticalGlue() );
deadPieces.add( deadWhitePieces );
frame.add(deadPieces. BorderLayout.LINE_START);
```

Then you add labels to the appropriate panel as required. For example:

```
deadWhitePieces.add( new JLabel(...) );
deadWhitePieces.revalidate();
deadWhitePieces.repaint();
```

Comment: (1+) you had a better understanding of the problem than I did. touche.